# Approach towards running parallel apps and services on VR device

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculusquest, magic-leap

Our intention is to develop numerous applications for Magic Leap 2 and Oculus Quest. These applications will share some fundamental features. To accommodate these applications, we want to create a distinct service with shared functionality to cut down on implementation time and device processing burden.

Is it possible to run multiple apps and services simultaneously on these devices? If so, how can we go about doing it? If not, are there any alternative ways to accomplish this?